# Rational functions on hyperelliptic Riemann surface

Tags: riemann-surfaces, divisors, hyperelliptic-curves

Let $\mathcal R$ be an hyperelliptic Riemann surface of genus $g\geq 1$. Is it true that the only possible rational functions on $\mathcal R$ with $\leq g$ poles are the liftings of rational functions on $\mathbb C$ to $\mathcal R$?

Equivalently, is it true that all principal divisors on $\mathcal R$ of the form
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m P_j - \sum_{j=1}^m Q_j
$$
with $m \leq g$, are the involution-symmetric ones (i.e. those for which each point is included along with its image by the hyperelliptic involution)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes (the answer was given, then deleted, by Francesco Polizzi). If $D$ and $D'$ are the divisors  of zeroes (resp. poles) of a rational function, the linear system $|D|$ has dimension $r\geq 1$ and is base point free (the supports of $D$ and $D'$ do not meet). If $\deg(D)\leq g$, this implies $D\sim rg^1_2$ as a consequence of geometric Riemann-Roch -- see e.g. Arbarello et al., p. 13. Now the elements of $rg^1_2$ for $r<g$ are invariant under the hyperelliptic involution, hence your statement.

Comment: Thanks @abx, although I have to work out the details (and especially, the notation) from Arbarello et al, this is a good start!